# Force an Integer To Be At Least 2 Digits Long

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can someone give me code to do the following....

if the integer is 1-9 display a string 01,02,03 etc.. if 10 or over leave it as is.

```
string display = yourInt.ToString("00");
```

DOES NOT WORK

Comment: What value must `yourInt` be that it doesn't work in, because this DOES work

Comment: this does actually work, can you show an example where it does not?

Comment: It works if yourInt is actually Int32.

Comment: Based on the other questions you asked - are you using this technique to set the value of a cell in Excel? If so, that would be extremely pertinent information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any language (at least the ones i know) and integer value type will never have `2` digits length in any value below `10`.

To display it with always a two digits length (as `02`, `05`, `12`) you must convert your number to String and then `padding` it with `0`.

Or you will evaluate it like:

```
String newValue = String.Format("{0:00}", yourInt);
```

As you see you will have to convert it to string before displaying it...

Comment: I hope `intValue` is never negative.

Comment: Why so much downvotes? The answer is technically correct. A bit weird, but correct.

Answer (score 57):

```
string display = yourInt.ToString("00");
```

Comment: +1 for getting there 10 seconds earlier.

Comment: That doesnt work. That will work of decimals after the deciamls, but its not working for whole numbers

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: It does work based on your description of the problem. Hence the upvotes Anthony has received. Could you clarify in what sense it "doesn't work" for you?

Comment: http://ideone.com/tdKAg says it works.

Comment: @Nick:  Decimals after decimals?  Not sure what you mean.  An integer doesn't have any numbers after the decimal.  That's what makes it an integer.  Oh, and to support everyone else.  "Yes, it does work."

Comment: I think it works.
In VS 2010 I put 
int x = 4;
string xx = x.ToString("00");
Console.WriteLine(xx);
And it outputs 04.

Comment: public static void Main (string[] args)
{
 int num = 9;
 var text = num.ToString ("00");
 Console.WriteLine (text); // outputs 09
}

Answer (score 13):

Or, in `String.Format` syntax (used in `Console.WriteLine`, for example)

```
string s = String.Format("{0:00}", yourInt);
```

Comment: This doesnt work it does the same thing as ToString("00") which wont add a leading zero

Comment: @Nick: Seriously, man, have even tried this or are you just assuming that you know what will happen?

Comment: I just tried it several times it returns for example 1 returns 1, 2 returns 2, 3 returns 3 etc I need 01,02,03

Comment: Your results are interesting.  I does indeed work as I described.  1 returns "01", as expected.  Look at the documentation for Composite Formatting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), and note that the formatString (the part after the colon) is the same as described for Custom Numeric Format Strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why `.ToString("00")` didn't work.  This test succeeds...

```
[TestMethod]
public void RightPadIntegersWithZero() {
  var values = new [] { -100, -20, -1, 0, 1, 5, 10, 100, 567 };
  var expecteds = new [] { "-100", "-20", "-01", "00", "01", "05", "10", "100", "567" };

  for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
    var value = values[i];
    var expected = expecteds[i];

    var result = value.ToString("00");
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
  }
}
```

You must be doing something different than what your question describes

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous: display it where?

In any case, you will probably want to look at [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you want?

```
for (int i = -20; i < 100; i++)
{
 string s = i.ToString();
 while (s.Length < 2) s = "0" + s;
 Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I realize it's a bit of a brute force approach as written here.  But if it did the trick, you could optimize it with a reusable character array instead of appending the string.